# MySQL performance is degraded after upgrading from 5.0.96 to 5.7.3

Tags: mysql, performance

I am facing severe performance issue after moving from MySQL version 5.0.96 to MySQL 5.7.3.  The query which runs in 1.7 sec in older version is taking 30 sec to execute.  Do you guys have any idea what parameter i need to fix to get adequate performance?
Looking for help.

## performance #mysql

I checked Explain plan in 5.0.96 and 5.7.3 both are different and i dont know how to make Explain plan same for both

(from Comment)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT c.supplierid, d.suppliername
    FROM  transhipmentinvoice a, transhipment_dtl b, suppitemmaster c,
        suppliermaster d, packagingmaster e
    WHERE  a.tsid = b.tsid
      AND  a.warehouse = 'waluj'
      AND  b.EBCollection = 'N'
      AND  b.consignor = c.supplierid
      AND  c.category = 'PACKAGE'
      AND  b.consignor = d.supplierid
      AND  b.dispatchto = c.buyerid
      AND  c.supplierid = d.supplierid
      AND  a.warehouse = e.wname
      AND  b.Consignor = e.supplierid
      AND  c.supplierid = e.supplierid
      AND  d.supplierid = e.supplierid
      AND  e.IsRetainable = 'Y'
      AND  e.PacID = b.PacID
    ORDER BY  suppliername
```

i tried option of setting optimizor switch as
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'

This code is running in 1.0 second in 5.0.96
and 5.7.3 version it takes 25 sec and above

Comment: Without seeing the query and the explain plan, we cannot tell you anything specific. The only general idea (especially if it affects all your queries) is a misconfiguration (e.g. you didn't (correcty) adjust your memory settings, or not suited to whichever of [innodb,myisam] your are using). In that case, configuration problems would fit better on https://dba.stackexchange.com. though, and provide at least your configuration settings. Also: 5.7.3 is a 6 year old milestone release (e.g. not even expected to be fully functional), why not use a more recent release if you upgrade anyway?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT    c.supplierid, d.suppliername FROM    transhipmentinvoice a, transhipment_dtl b, suppitemmaster c,   suppliermaster d, packagingmaster e  WHERE a.tsid = b.tsid AND a.warehouse = 'waluj'   AND b.EBCollection = 'N'  AND b.consignor = c.supplierid   AND c.category = 'PACKAGE' AND b.consignor = d.supplierid AND b.dispatchto = c.buyerid  AND c.supplierid = d.supplierid  AND a.warehouse = e.wname  AND b.Consignor = e.supplierid AND c.supplierid = e.supplierid  AND d.supplierid = e.supplierid  AND e.IsRetainable = 'Y'  AND e.PacID = b.PacID ORDER BY suppliername

Comment: Above is the query that runs faster in lower version and slow in the higher version

Comment: Please edit it into your question (the edit button on the left side under your question). Also add the explain plan (the output of `explain select ...`) for both of your mysql versions. Also mention if this is a general problem (all queries are slow -> maybe memory configuration) or only some. We'd also like to see our table definitions, at least their indexes (although the problem might be clear from the explain plans). It is relevant though if you are using innodb or myisam for the new tables (since you may be using the original db from 5.0 when myisam was still the default).

Comment: Please use the newer syntax of `JOIN ... ON` to make the relationships clear.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Roughly how big is each table?  Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`